# C# - Start Function After Closing Form

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I have 2 forms. One is the display form and the other is the where data is added to an array.

How do I start a function on the display form once the ok button has been clicked on the add to array form?

**EDIT:**

Let me rephrase. How would I go about calling a function that is in one .cs file, from another .cs file.

**Form 1**

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2= new Form2();
    form2.Owner = this;
    form2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

**Form 2**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.myMethod();
}
```

Obviously, the form2 code is generating a new instance of form1.

How do I run the method of the form that opened the modal window?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code and explain what you are seeing and what you expected to see.

Comment: Is there common single place where two forms are instantiated or somehow interact? The idea is to inject callback function

Comment: All forms are "display forms". Are you using a hidden form just to hold some data?

Comment: A Windows [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) is always a "display form" because its the GUI. You should make your "Array-Form" a class that not inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Comment: by display form i meant it is the form that displays all the data.

Comment: To answer we need to know how the two form interact. Is the 'display' form the owner and show modally the 'array' form? Also do you need the array data in the 'display' form?

Comment: The array is put into a listview which i need to clear and reload with the new data

Comment: is it two separate forms, or one is called from another as modal? pls more code

Comment: the 'add to array' form is a modal form, shown after a button is clicked on the main 'display' form.

Comment: you can use event handler for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of `Form2` is a instance of `Form1` so you can cast the owner to `Form1` and call the method:

```
(this.Owner as Form1).myMethod();
```