# Use method after close form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I want to call a method in my class form1.cs after closing form2.cs

**form1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var form2= new form2();
  form2.Show(); 
}

public void Form1Refresh()
{
  //some code 
}
```

**form2:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...

  Close();

  //call refresh from form1

}
```

How can i used the method Refresh() after closing the form ? I try it with `new form1` and call the function but this used a new object and doesnt work.

Should i pass the object of the form1 to form2 and use it or is there another solution ?

Comment: Use C# Casting Cihck this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498019/c-sharp-start-function-after-closing-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create and show your `Form2` handle its `FormClosed` event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.FormClosed += form2_FormClosed; // This Line
    form2.Show();
}

void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("Form 2 has been closed. Call the Refresh Action");
}
```

Comment: Works Great Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably a duplicate.

You could hook the FormClosed event when you're constructing Form2 on the button press in Form1

```
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        form2.FormClosed += (sender, eventArgs) => { Refresh(); };
```

Windows Forms already contain a method called `Refresh`, did you intend to hide the method from the baseclass? I'd suggest giving it a different name or at least call the `base.Refresh();` from your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the MainWindow and parse it to Form1.

Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;

((form1)window).Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

try this code

FORM1:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
            f2.Show();
        }

 public void Form1Refresh()
        {
           ///////

        }
```

FORM2:

```
 public Form1 f1;
        public Form2(Form1 m)
        {
          this.f1 = m;
            InitializeComponent();
        }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            f1.Form1Refresh();     

        }
```